# generate random number in c++

Tags: c++, random, random-seed

I get a task to generate tens of thousands random number in c++. I've googled a lot about random number in c++ and look up the c++ reference, but I got confused now.

As I know, random_device is a non-deterministic random number generator, but every time I re-run my program, the random number generated by random_device is the same. So how do I set a seed for random_device to make the random number is different when I restart my program?

And I've read that "std::random_device could run out of entropy if you try to get a lot of numbers from it. That could cause it to block until you move the mouse or something". That means my program could pause at some time. How can I avoid this happening?

Comment: What compiler are you using? `std::random_device` is ***broken*** in `MinGW`.

Comment: I am using GNU or g++ under ubuntu.

Comment: Can you post some short example code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I think this answer may answer some of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662280/c-need-a-good-technique-for-seeding-rand-that-does-not-use-time/50665027#50665027

Comment: Why do you need a different set for each program run?

Comment: "And I've read that "std::random_device could run out of entropy if you try to get a lot of numbers from it. That could cause it to block until you move the mouse or something". That means my program could pause at some time. How can I avoid this happening?" - is your target architecture a ZX81?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device), you can see `std::random_device` does not always guarantee to be non-deterministic:

> std::random_device may be implemented in terms of an implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine **if a non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available** to the implementation. In this case each std::random_device object **may generate the same number sequence**.

On Linux, it by default uses `/dev/urandom` or `RDRND` CPU instruction according to [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/random_device):

> The implementations in libc++ and libstdc++ expect token to be the name of a character device that produces random numbers when read from, with the **default value "/dev/urandom"**, although **where the CPU instruction RDRND is available, libstdc++ uses that as the default**.

which **won't block**. You can switch to a even secured device `/dev/random` using approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726331/c-extracting-random-numbers-from-dev-urandom), but that device will block if not having enough entropy.

On Windows, I'm not sure about such device therefore it might fall back to some PRNG which requires some kind of seed.

To solve the problem cross-platformly, as @Binara mentioned, you can use `std::rand` from `<cstdlib>`. This function will not block, and you can use `std::srand(somethingLikeCurrentTime)` to make it *some-what* non-deterministic.

As @user1118321 mentioned, if you want to use a more secured PRNG, you might consider `std::mersenne_twister_engine` and use `std::random_device` to generate a seed of it. This approach is suggested [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't  need cryptographically secure random number generation, then you can  use the `std::mt19937` random generator.  It's the [Meresenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) random generator that has a period of 2<sup>19937</sup> iterations before it repeats. I've used it  like this in the past:

```
std::array<int, std::mt19937::state_size> seedData;
std::random_device  randDevice;
std::mt19937 eng;
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> randGen(0, 1);
std::generate_n(seedData.data(), seedData.size(), std::ref(randDevice));
std::seed_seq seq(std::begin(seedData), std::end(seedData));
eng.seed(seq);
```

That creates an  array containing the seed  of the appropriate size. It creates a random device to set up the seed. Then it creates an `mt19937` random generator engine to generate the numbers. To use it to generate values between 0 and 1 you can use  the `std::uniform_real_distribution`  like this:

```
double randVal = randGen(eng);
```