# A good source of entropy for seeding a CSPRNG?

Tags: c++, cryptography, entropy

In c++, would using the std::chrono::high_resolution_clock to time any function call repeatedly be a good source of entropy?

Comment: `std::random_device` is what's commonly used. Example: `std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());`

Comment: RDRAND instruction, arrival times of network packets or keyboard characters, audio noise from mic. Someone made a RNG from a lava lamp.

Comment: See https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/simple-portable-cpp-seed-entropy.html

Comment: Any clock is not a good cryptographically secure seed.  You need as wide a range of entropy sources as you can manage, including a clock, but also including as many other sources as available.  A good place to start might be the cryptographically secure PRNG provided by your operating system, since that will have access to various under-the-hood sources not available to normal programs.

Comment: /dev/urandom that is the key. https://stackoverflow.com/q/35726331/1820553